# string arithmetic in cpp

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I wrote code for ceasar cipher but it gave wrong answer in some input. I doubt that after addition ASCII value is get negative. Please help out.

```
int main() {

    int N,k,i=0;
    string s;
    cin >> N;
    cin >> s;
    cin >> k;

    if(N < 1 || N > 100 || k >100 || k < 0)
        return 0;

    if(k >= 26 )
        k = k%26;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(s[i] >= 65 && s[i] <= 90)
        {
            s[i] += k;
            if(s[i] > 90)
                s[i] -= 26;
        }
        if(s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122)
        {
            s[i] += k;
            if(s[i] > 122 )
                s[i] -= 26;
        }
    }

    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
   10
   www.abc.xy
   87
```

Expected output:

```
   fff.jkl.gh
```

My output:

```
   .jkl.
```

Comment: You *are* allowed to write `'A'` instead of `65`, and so on. There's no need to encrypt the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the part for the lowercase letters

```
if(s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122)
{
   s[i] += k;
   if(s[i] > 122 )
      s[i] -= 26;
}
```

you have a overflow problem (possibly). Convert the char first
to something between 0 and 26, and after applying the Caesar stuff, revert it:

```
if(s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
{
   s[i] -= 'a';
   s[i] += k;
   s[i] %= 26;
   s[i] += 'a';
}
```

Similar for the uppercase letters.

Other than that:
You should really use `s.length()` instead of letting the user descide what N is.
And what happens if k is negative?

Btw., Arithm**e**tic and C**ae**s**a**r.

Comment: yes, you are right, but why we have overflow problem. can't we perform arithmetic operation on string directly ?

Comment: OK I got it ..char is 8 bit so store upto 127 only...:)

Comment: @NikunjAadesara 8bit are 256 different values, but it can differ what a `char` is. Either 0 to 255, or -128 to +127, or...

Comment: so for overflow problem we can use unsigned char also if limits allowed to do so...And for this code unsigned char works well

Answer (score -1):

**Problem is only in ASCII - CHAR conversion**

***This will surely work***

```
int N,k,i=0;
string s;
cin >> N;
cin >> s;
cin >> k;
if(N < 1 || N > 100 || k >100 || k < 0)
    return 0;

if(k >= 26 )
{
    k = k%26;
}
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    if(s[i] >= 65 && s[i] <= 90)
    {   int t=(int)s[i];
        t += k;
        if(t > 90)
            t -= 26;
s[i]=(char)t;
    }
    if(s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122)
    {
int t=(int)s[i];
t+=k;
if(t>122)
t-=26;
s[i]=(char)t;
    }
}

cout << s;
return 0;
```